# Does decimals makes up a number or a number contains decimals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I dont really know whether this question is right or wrong, but i am sort of confused,  There is a number `1` and then there is number `2`, there are some decimal numbers between this `1 and 2` like `1.1` `1.2` upto `1.9`, now, does this number `2` has formed because of these decimal numbers or this number `2` contains these decimal numbers? or is it both, i dont really know how to ask this question in a methodical way, is there a theory that explains this

Comment: It does not contain them (unless you define *number* and *contains* in a special way).  Nor is it formed because of them.  But it is their supremum.

Comment: It's hard to understand what distinction you are asking about, so it might help if you described a situation where it would make a difference. Because if it would never make a difference, then most mathematicians wouldn't care, and you should probably go ask some philosophers.

Comment: This sounds a little bit like Dedekind cuts, but even there you need the rational numbers to "exist" on their own first.

Comment: Is this your own question? If not, can you provide the context?  If it is, what are you trying to understand more broadly, the real numbers?  Because there is a set of natural numbers which contains 1 and 2, but nothing in between.

Comment: @Joe it is my own question, trying to understand the numbers, just starting.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Since you are a programmer, you should be familiar with the concept of `types`.  A boolean, an int, a float, a string... all of these may have different ways of storing the data and different methods available to it.  In the same way, in maths we have several different objects who we use the symbol "$2$" for and it is unclear which $2$ you are specifically asking about.  $2$ the natural number, $2$ the integer, $2$ the rational number, $2$ the real number, $2$ the complex number... When defining the natural number $2$ it is very simply "the number after $1$"

Comment: Decimals don't even exist when talking about natural numbers... all there are are numbers like $1,2,3,4,\dots$ going up by $1$ each time.  In that sense, the natural number $2$ has neither "formed because of" the decimal numbers between $1$ and $2$ nor "contains" them.  Indeed, going to integers and rational numbers as well, we can define $2$ without ever having to think about the numbers between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Now... moving to the reals... yes, there are various formal ways of defining them and the phrasing you used sounds similar to the formal phrasing used when talking about dedekind cuts when defining what we mean when we talk about a real number... however I *strongly* doubt you are using the words in the same way and intend to have the same meaning.  Most people never reach the point of needing to formally define reals and are content to just think of $2$ as "the number 1 larger than 1" and not think any harder about it than that, and until you reach higher maturity I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I'm not sure in which way you are "trying to understand" them, or which "numbers" you are referring to, but you should clarify that, at least to yourself. Many math courses in college increased my understanding of numbers in some way. In abstract algebra we studied binary operations and different structures such as rings, groups, and fields. In number theory we studied the natural numbers and concepts like divisibility, factorization, prime numbers, etc.  In real analysis we studied the axioms of the real numbers. Only after college did I read some books on set theory and the Peano axioms.